# excel vba remove duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below table :

```
Name, Total, Email Address  Date
Test1,12,test1@hotmail.com  12/12/2012
Test2,12,test1@hotmail.com  12/05/2015
Test2,12,test1@hotmail.com  12/05/2015
Test3,12,test1@hotmail.com  12/07/2016
```

I want to match on Name, Email Address and Date. If an existing record is found then I want to merge them and add the totals together. e.g.

```
Test2,12,test1@hotmail.com  12/05/2015
Test2,12,test1@hotmail.com  12/05/2015
```

would become

```
Test2,24,test1@hotmail.com  12/05/2015
```

What options do I have?. If i iterate sequentially and check for every one it would take a substantial amount of time.. (was thinking to use range check and check current row against all, if found then delete and add a new row).Would appreciate some examples.

Comment: i've added steps to my solution, please look at it, and see if it helps, if not feel free to ask what you don't understand

Answer (score 2):

You can add a 5th column and `CONCAT` columns Name,Email,Date, with commas between them. E.g. `Test1,test1@hotmail.com,12/12/2012`.

Export this column in another sheet and apply `Remove duplicates` so you have unique data.

Now apply a `SUMIF` according to this column and sum data from Total as:

```
SUMIF(range:"your tabel",criteria: the 5th column, sum range: column Total)
```

Answer (score 0):

why not simply have column E sum the values like this:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"="&A2,C:C,"="&C2,D:D,"="&D2)
```

and when you finish copy as values and remove duplicates using the function on the ribbon? this way you can copy at the end column E to column B and be done with it in a couple of minutes
edited: clarity and steps

### those are the steps needed

1. place the following formula in cell E1, and pull it down until it's in all of column E until the end of the data

   `=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"="&A2,C:C,"="&C2,D:D,"="&D2)`
2. copy column E into column E - **as values**
3. use excel's **remove duplicates** function
4. copy column E to column B

and that's the full steps needed to accomplish your task.

Comment: Do I not need to apply the sumifs on every line?

Comment: Yes you should. After adding the formula to column E, copy it as values in place to column E, then use remove duplicate,  and copy column E to column B.  i'm not next to a computer now, I'll edit the answer with ordered steps when I get back home

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

1. The list is sorted by ColA
2. Your table header is in Row3
3. There is only 1 duplicate
4. If ColA is the same, so are C and D

   ```
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim cellCount As Integer

   cellCount = Application.CountA(Range("A:A")) - 1

   For i = 4 To cellCount
       If (Cells(i, "A").Value = Cells(i + 1, "A").Value) Then
           Cells(i, "B").Value = Cells(i, "B").Value + Cells(i + 1, "B").Value
       End If
   Next i

   ActiveSheet.Range("A:D").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
   ```